# Avoid looping to get one particular column of values from Set<Entity> in Java

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop

I have a code snippet in Java as follows:

```
Set<BookDO> bookSet = shopDO.getBooks();
    Collection<String> bookCollection = null;
    if (bookSet != null && !bookSet .isEmpty()) {
      bookCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (BookDO book : bookSet) {
        bookCollection .add(book.getName());
      }
    }
```

Finally I want the only Collection of book names to pass it to an API which displays the output.

Is it possible to avoid the **for loop** to improve performance ?

Answer (score 4):

You should not worry about the performance of the loop construct. There is a JIT, that will optimize things at runtime.

You have a Set of Books, containing **n** elements. You want to retrieve a property of each set entry; and push that value into a list. That is simply not possible without *somehow* iterating that whole set! You know, in order to touch **every** element, you have to, well, touch **every** element.

Yes, using java8 streams, this could be rewritten in various ways; and you might *gain* a bit of performance because that will enable the compiler to use the [invokedynamic](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/learn-java/invokedynamic-101.html) bytecode instruction (which has certain performance advantages).

But in the end: you don't get around iterating over all entries of that collection.

And the real take away is: you are only **assuming** that you have a performance problem. Don't try to fix something that isn't real; until it becomes a **real** issue. Of course, if that collections contains many zillions of entries, then you do have a **real** problem. But then your question is still going in the wrong direction; because if you are doing "hardcore" data crunching; you would have to re-think your complete design to find ways to "scale".

Caveat: if we would be talking quantum computing, and [Grover search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), then, well, crazy things would be possible. But we aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late update:

No. It is not possible right out of current code (aside of using Java 8 features to hide it)

If `shopDO.getBooks();` code is in your hands you have another options :

- if Book Name is unique use Map instead of Set with Name as a key.
  then you have your Book names right out of it as `bookMap.keySet()`
- if Book Name is not unique you can return from `shopDO` two collections 1. `Set<BookDO>` and `List<String>` of names populated at the same time when you populate first `Set`

If you cannot modify `shopDo` code then there is no options.

Comment: Right. It just hides under different language level code structure. So it is an "illusion" that there is no loop. :-)

Comment: No problem. I just typed from phone which I'm not good with... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Possible but you can optimize that code using lambda expression

```
Set<BookDO> bookSet = [dataSorce]
Collection<String> bookCollection;
if (bookSet != null && bookSet.isEmpty()) {
    bookCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
    bookSet.forEach((book) -> {
        bookCollection.add(book.getName());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Java8 - use lambdas. They are compiled differently and good for JIT - this construction will act faster.

```
Collection<String> bookCollection = bookSet.stream().map(BookDO::getName()).collect(toSet())
```

You also may store map instead of set if the collection is not changing.
bookMap = new HashMap
You'll have to create map only once (HasSet uses HashMap in it's implementation, so there will be no performance or memory issues). When you need to get books you call:

```
bookMap.keySet();
```

When names:

```
bookMap.values();
```